# Splitting big block of binary into 8 bit chunks in bash

Tags: bash, split, grep

I have a large block of binary, take this for an example:

```
000110101100101001110001010101110010101010110101
```

(Not sure if the example is a multiple of 8 but...)

I'd like to split this block of text into 8 bit chunks, and output it to a file line by line, i.e. like:

```
00011010
11001010
01110001
etc...
```

Apologies if this is really simple, I've attempted using 'split' but can't get the right syntax and I'd ideally like to do this in bash. Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this with grep:

```
grep -Eo '.{8}' file > newfile
```

Output to newfile:

```
00011010
11001010
01110001
01010111
00101010
```

Same output to newfile with fold from [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities):

```
fold -w 8 file > newfile
```